# Como eliminar la primer y ultima cadena repetida de ceros de un String

Tags: java

Necesito poder eliminar la primer y también la ultima secuencia de ceros repetidas de un `String` en Java

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente String

```
00000000110110110011100000
```

Y necesito transformarlo a

```
1101101100111
```

Comment: a priori se me ocurre un substring desde la posicion 0 hasta la posicion del primer 1 y al substring restante desde la pos 0 hasta el ultimo 1 algo asi 'stg=mystr.subatring(indexOf('0'),mystr.lenght);' ' stg=stg.substring(0,stg.lastimdexOf('1')'; A ver esta mal escrito por llevo muchos años sn programar en java, pero es primero elimiminar la primera cadena de ceros y al resultado eliminar la ultima

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código que has avanzado para solucionar dicho problema.

Comment: Agregué unmétodo para usar en este caso, incluso cuando tu cadena no contiene "1", saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo para sumar una respuesta mas, y como ejemplo de como se puede hacer esto en una sola linea, ya que estamos hablando de un string, lo mejor es usar las funciones que ya existen para string para resolver este caso.

La funcion trim, remueve espacios atras y adelante.. pero aca no tenemos espacios, tenemos 0. Pero que pasa si cambiamos esos 0 por espacios?

```
String s = "00000000110110110011100000";
String r = s.replace("0"," ").trim().replace(" ","0");
```

En este caso, r va a contener exactamente la cadena que pides.

Comment: Esto me parece excelente haha y mucho más corta!

Comment: Es la mejor respuesta de las planteadas, ya la probe y funciona.

Answer (score 1):

La ubicación del primer dígito `1`:

```
cadena.indexOf('1');
```

La ubicación del último dígito `1`:

```
cadena.lastIndexOf('1');
```

Usando ambos resultados, puedes crear un método que haga lo que esperas.

```
public static String trimZeros(String s) {
    String resultado = "";
    int indiceMenor = s.indexOf('1');
    //si indiceMenor es menor a 0 entonces la cadena s está compuesta solo por "0"s.
    if (indiceMenor >= 0) {
        int indiceMayor = s.lastIndexOf('1');
        //solo existe 1 "1"
        if (indiceMayor == indiceMenor) {
            resultado = "1";
        } else {
            resultado = s.substring(indiceMenor, indiceMayor+1);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Demostración:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(trimZeros("00000"));
    System.out.println(trimZeros("00100"));
    System.out.println(trimZeros("01010"));
}
```

Salida

```
  <-- en blanco porque removió todos los 0s
1
101
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa esta pequeña funcion, le envías cadena y carácter que quieres limpiar:

```
public static String eliminaCaracterIzqDer(String cad, char cadEliminar){
    String[] acad=cad.split("");
    int posL = 0,posR = acad.length;
    for(int i=0;i<acad.length;i++){
        if(!acad[i].equals(Character.toString(cadEliminar))){posL=i;break;}
    }
    for(int i=acad.length;i>0;i--){
        if(!acad[i-1].equals(Character.toString(cadEliminar))){posR=i;break;}            
    }
    return cad.substring(posL,posR);
}
```

Lo invocas:

```
System.out.println(eliminaCaracterIzqDer("000001254780900",'0'));
```

Resultado: `12547809`

Comment: la funcion esta mal, el parametro cadEliminar no se usa nunca porque hardcodeaste el 0.

Comment: vale lo copie de mis pruebas, lo ajusto ahora, Gracias por la observación.

Comment: otro problema si cad a eliminar fuera "00" entonces la funcion no eliminaria nunca nada.. nada que ver con lo que pide el usuario, pero en tu caso habria que validar que el segundo string en realidad fuera un char... y no un string...

Comment: Claro que no eliminaría, porque la función valida por carácter no grupo de caracteres. Seguro que tendrías un idea original o quizás te sirva de idea para algo mejor. Suerte.

Comment: No lo tomes a mal. no es mi idea criticar, solo esta bueno dejarlo en claro para futuros usuarios que vean la función, la cual esta muy buena. Las otras respuestas implementadas no usan este método, y si uno ya sabe las limitaciones es mejor avisarlas.

Comment: No te preocupes, solo respondo porque a mi parecer "si tiene que ver con lo que pide el usuario" y hasta da mas opciones que eliminar solo "0". En fin somos libres de usarlo o no, solo es mi aporte.

Comment: OK. tiene razón el comentario de arriba no fue del todo feliz y te pido disculpas.

Comment: No hay problema, es valida tu sugerencia, me sirvió para actualizar el código. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como una opción, puedes usar un [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) y los métodos [delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int)) para eliminar las secuencias de ceros al inicio y al final:

```
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("00000000110110110011100000");

 int start = str.indexOf("1");      
 str.delete(0, start); //Elimina ceros al inicio.
 int end = str.lastIndexOf("1")+1;
 str.delete(end, str.length()); //Elimina ceros al final.

 System.out.println("Resultado : " + str);
```

Teniendo como resultado:

```
Resultado : 1101101100111
```

---

Pero, **¿Que sucedería si no se tienen valores de 1 en tu String?**, para esto aquí tienes una versión mejorada de lo anterior que cumple para todos los casos:

```
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("0000000000000");

 int start = str.indexOf("1");
 if(start>-1){ //Valida si encuentra primera coincidencia de 1
     str.delete(0, start);
 }
 int end = str.lastIndexOf("1");
 if(end>-1){ //Valida si encuentra última coincidencia de 1
    str.delete(end + 1, str.length());
 }     
 if(start <0 && end <0 ){ //no encontro valores de 1
   str.delete(0, str.length());   //Elimina todos los 0
 }
```

Teniendo como resultado:

```
Resultado :
```

Agrego un método que cumple con todos los casos y puedes usar en tu programa:

```
   private static String eliminaCeros(String valor){

     StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(valor);     

     int start = str.indexOf("1");
     if(start>-1){ //Valida si encuentra primera coincidencia de 1
         str.delete(0, start);
     }
     int end = str.lastIndexOf("1");
     if(end>-1){ //Valida si encuentra última coincidencia de 1
        str.delete(end + 1, str.length());
     }     

     if(start <0 && end <0 ){ //no encontro valores de 1
       str.delete(0, str.length());  
     }        
       return str.toString();
    }
```

Además un [**ejemplo online**](https://ideone.com/JLBcsL) para que pruebes el método.

---

Otra opción es comentada por gbianchi que me parece excelente y más corta.

- Convierte los 0 en espacios de la cadena original `00000000110110110011100000`:

`11 11 11  111`

- Elimina los espacios en los extremos mediante el método `.trim()`:

`11 11 11  111`

- Vuelve a llenar los espacios con ceros, por lo tanto el resultado es:

`1101101100111`

Este sería un método con este ejemplo:

```
   public static String validaNumeros(String valor){  
        return valor.replace("0"," ").trim().replace(" ","0");
   }
```